# Should I use 'to' with home and house?

Tags: grammar, tense, word-usage

> let's go home.
>
> let's go to home.
>
> let's go house.
>
> let's go to house.
>
> I'm going home
>
> I'm going to home

When should I use 'home' and when should I use 'house'.

Comment: Additional information: *House* is a particular kind of building. *Home* is where people live. People can live in a house, an apartment, a condominium, even an RV, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

There is a noun *home* and a noun *house*. There is also a preposition *home* too.

The most important aspect for this question is the preposition *home*, but I'll say a little bit about the nouns *house* and *home* first.

**The noun *House***

Your *house* is the physical building that you live in - and it must be a house, not a flat! A house has rooms on the ground floor. It also usually has a front door on the ground floor. A flat is not a house!

Here's a picture of some houses:

[image: Doug Bird's picture of houses]

Here's a picture of some flats:

[image]

So *houses* are physical buildings. A *flat* is part of a larger physical building.

**The noun *Home***

Your *home* is any place where you feel that you belong. It is usually a safe place. It's a place that you know very, very well. It's a place you look after and like to be in  - usually. It might be a house or a flat or a caravan, or a city, or even a country. If you know a city well and you feel good there, and you feel that you belong there, you can say:

- This city is my home.

It doesn't matter whether a home is a type of building or not. Many animals have homes. They don't usually have flats or houses though!

**The preposition *home***

We can use the preposition *home* like other prepositions, for example *in, up, down, inside*. The preposition *home* means "to or in your home":

- Go in
- Go up
- Go down
- Go inside
- Go home

Like with other prepositions we can use the preposition *home* with the verb *BE*:

- She is in.
- Prices are up
- The lever is down.
- The box is inside.
- She isn't home.

Like many other prepositions, *home* can occur with other prepositions:

- out of the window
- from inside
- down in the depths
- at home

With the verb *GO*, we don't use the preposition *to* as well as another preposition. The following sentences are ungrammatical:

- *She went to in the door. (X)
- *The lift is going to up. (X)
- *The lift is going to down. (X)
- *I walked to inside the building. (X)
- *She went to home. (X)

We use the special adverbs *straight* and *right* with prepositions:

- Go straight in
- We went right up to the top of the mountain
- The lift went straight down to the ground floor.
- I went right inside.
- She went straight home.

**Note**

Notice that we *can* use nouns after the preposition *to*. So the following sentences are ok:

- I went to the cinema
- I travelled to the Andes.
- I went to my friend's home.
- I went to my friend's house.

Here we are using the noun *home*, not the preposition. If you use the noun *home* in this way it will usually have a determiner (*a, the, this, my* ...) or it will be plural. It may also have adjectives:

- I'm going to different homes in the area.

In the example above, we see the noun *home*. We know it's the noun because it is plural *homes* not *home*. Also, it has an adjective *different*. Notice that in this example, the noun *homes* does not have a determiner. Because we are using the noun *home*, we still need to use the preposition *to* with the verb *GO* here.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: A dialect note: "a flat" is very British (Commonwealth?) English.  In the US, we call that _an apartment_.

Comment: I wonder why _home_ is a preposition as opposed to an adverb. Most online dictionaries list this usage as preposition. I know dictionaries are not 100% correct especially when it comes to parts of speech (I also remember you emphasizing that in a comment to one of my questions on ELU). But if _home_ is a preposition in _go home_, can we follow that phrase with a noun? _go home + noun_?

Comment: Hi @Eddie, see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468152/what-part-of-speech-is-back-in-if-you-want-it-back/468176#468176) for a description of *intransitive prepositions* :) Bit too long for a comment box!

Comment: @Araucaria It's crystal clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*Generally,* the word 'house' refers to a building. On the other hand, the word *home* has some emotions in that.

The preposition *at* is possible with *home.*

> Let's go. She must be *at home*

But then, use prepositions with *home* carefully. A note from the Cambridge Dictionary is very good to refer.

> We use home as an adverb with verbs of movement such as get, go, come, arrive, travel, drive. **We don’t use *'to'***.

I strongly recommend reading [the entire page.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/house-or-home) This clarifies many things about *home/house* and using prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason we say "to go home" is because in this use "Home" is an "adverb of place". "House" does not have that use so does not work in that form.

In "go to my home" and "go to my house" we are using them as nouns. Both words can be nouns, adjectives or verbs in the right context.

Other adverbs of place include "abroad", "upstairs", compass directions, and "outside"

(The differnce in meaning between "house" and "home" is why "housework" and "homework" are completely different activities.)

Answer (score 0):

The expression is "to go home". You don't say "to go to home" and you don't say 
"to go house". "to go home" is a fixed idiom that you can't change.

Comment: Hmmm, how about *go straight home*, *go right home*, *go via home* .... thay seem like modification of *go home* to me! ;-)