# Question about diffrenece between "go to home" & "go home"

Tags: prepositions

> **I am going home.**
>
> **I am going to home.**

Irrelevantly I should mention here that I perfectly know what the difference between **to** and **towards** is. My concern has to do with the meaning when we make the sentence without **to** or **towards**

Comment: Some other related questions that might help you with this: (1) [Should I use _to_ with _home_ and _house_](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49037), (2) [_stay home_ vs _stay at home_](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16153), (3) [Going home, going to school, going to the airport](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56381).

Answer (score 0):

Although many language learners say it, 'go to home' in any form is simply not standard English: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go%20to%20home%2C%20go%20home&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cgo%20to%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20to%20Home%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgo%20to%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20to%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20to%20Home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgo%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20home%3B%2Cc0).