# What time is it? or What is the time?

Tags: questions

How to analyze this question:

> **What time is it?**

my question is:  **What is the original sentence that forms  the above question?**

let's say:

> the time is 7:00 o'clock.

then Yes/No question should be:

> Is the time 7:00 o'clock?

if we want to ask about object, so the question should be:

> **What is the time?**

Comment: "*so the question should be*"? How did you arrive at that conclusion? Obviously you know that both are used. I suppose it depends on local preference.

Comment: Actually, the "original sentence" is usually "**It** is seven o'clock."

Comment: Both *What time is it?* and *What is the time?* are correct and used interchangeably.

Comment: You ask a lot of questions, but since you answer them, I actually wonder what you actually want to know.

Comment: @Laure actually, it is one question, and I don't answer it.

Comment: @stangdon thank you, so it is dummy it, isn't it?

Comment: @Shannak - That's a good question.  I'm not sure if it's a dummy it or not, because you could also say "The time is..." so maybe *it* refers to "the time".

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. The latter uses time as object, "What is the time" implies the time could be something. Whereas, "What time is it", ask for time as the property of an object, e.g. the clock (not to say the time). That would be an [adverbial objective](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56406/question-about-diffrenece-between-go-to-home-go-home), to be precise.

Comment: Don't forget that people mostly shorten it to **"What's the time?"** to ask for the current hour and minute.